# LiveChart ColumnSeries change default colors

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, livecharts

Today I downloaded and tried LiveChart for WinForms. I displayed a simple BasicColumn Chart. As you may know the default colors are red and blue. I want to change them to gray and orangen.Does anyone know how to do this? 
Thanks!

My code:

```
using(TechnoholzEntities db = new TechnoholzEntities())
            {
                var data = db.GetAngebotsData();
                ColumnSeries col = new ColumnSeries() { DataLabels = true, Values = new LiveCharts.ChartValues<decimal>(), LabelPoint = point => point.Y.ToString() };
                ColumnSeries col2 = new ColumnSeries() { DataLabels = true, Values = new LiveCharts.ChartValues<decimal>(), LabelPoint = point => point.Y.ToString()};

                Axis ax = new Axis() { Separator = new Separator() { Step = 1, IsEnabled = false } };
                ax.Labels = new List<string>();
                foreach(var x in data)
                {
                    col2.Values.Add(x.Kalksumme.Value);
                    col.Values.Add(x.Auftragssumme.Value);
                    ax.Labels.Add(x.Von.ToString());
                }

                cartesianChart1.Series.Add(col);
                cartesianChart1.Series.Add(col2);
                cartesianChart1.AxisX.Add(ax);
                cartesianChart1.AxisY.Add(new Axis
                {
                    LabelFormatter = value => value.ToString(),
                    Separator = new Separator()
                });
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

`ColumnSeries` has a property `Fill` which changes the color.

```
col.Fill = Brushes.Orange;
```